# Laravel Vue.js Conditional Rendering

Tags: php, laravel, vue.js

I am new to Vue.js and I want to render a form element only if another form select field is selected. I hope you understand what I mean.

Here st my Laravel Form:

```
<div class="form-group">
    {!! Form::label('mailarchive', 'Mailarchive: ', ['class' => 'col-sm-3 control-label']) !!}
    <div class="col-sm-6">
        {!! Form::select('mailarchive', ['-' => 'No', 'Gold' => 'Gold', 'Silver' => 'Silver', 'Bronze' => 'Bronze'], null, ['class' => 'form-control']) !!}
    </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    {!! Form::label('instance', 'Instance: ', ['class' => 'col-sm-3 control-label']) !!}
    <div class="col-sm-6">
        {!! Form::select('mailarchive', ['Select' => 'Select', '1' => 'SV01', '2' => 'SV02'], null, ['class' => 'form-control']) !!}
    </div>
</div>
```

The second form-group (label: instance) should only be visible when 'Gold', 'Silver' or 'Bronze' in the first select field is selected, but not visible if 'No' is selected.

Thanks for your help!

Wipsly

**// Update**

I edited my code to this

```
<div class="form-group">
    {!! Form::label('mailarchive', 'Mailarchive: ', ['class' => 'col-sm-3 control-label']) !!}
    <div class="col-sm-6">
        {!! Form::select('mailarchive', ['-' => 'No', 'Gold' => 'Gold', 'Silver' => 'Silver', 'Bronze' => 'Bronze'], null, ['class' => 'form-control v-model="mailarchive"']) !!}
    </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group v-show="mailarchive !='-'"">
    {!! Form::label('instance', 'Instance: ', ['class' => 'col-sm-3 control-label']) !!}
    <div class="col-sm-6">
        {!! Form::select('mailarchive', ['Select' => 'Select', '1' => 'SV01', '2' => 'SV02'], null, ['class' => 'form-control']) !!}
    </div>
</div>
```

And here is my javascript

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    new Vue({
        el: '#mailarchive'
    })
</script>
```

But nothing happens. What do I wrong?

Comment: This is more of a JS question than a laravel blade one.

Comment: Maybe... I have laravel in my topic because of the Laravel Blade Engine and HTML | Form Facade.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A lot to tackle here. First, you should set a "parent" Vue instance rather than creating a new Vue instance for individual input fields. For example, lets say you want to make the entire form a Vue instance, then when you open your form, set an id like this:

```
{!! Form::open(['id' => 'example']) !!}
```

Then, when you create your Vue instance, reference that id:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    new Vue({
        el: '#example'
    })
</script>
```

Next, this code you have is incorrect:

```
{!! Form::select('mailarchive', ['-' => 'No', 'Gold' => 'Gold', 'Silver' => 'Silver', 'Bronze' => 'Bronze'], null, ['class' => 'form-control v-model="mailarchive"']) !!}
```

Specifically, pay attention to this part: `['class' => 'form-control v-model="mailarchive"']`

What you are doing here is creating some weird class. When you specify extra HTML attributes, you need to pass an array of those attributes like this:

```
{!! Form::select('mailarchive', ['-' => 'No', 'Gold' => 'Gold', 'Silver' => 'Silver', 'Bronze' => 'Bronze'], null, ['class' => 'form-control', 'v-model' => 'mailarchive']) !!}
```

From there, another problem is how you are using `v-show`.

This is what you have: `<div class="form-group v-show="mailarchive !='-'"">`

Once again, for some reason, you are putting v-directives inside your class. Instead, use it as its own HTML attribute like this:

```
<div class="form-group" v-show="mailarchive !== '-'">
```

All that together, you should see something like this:

```
{!! Form::open(['id' => 'example']) !!}
    <div class="form-group">
        {!! Form::label('mailarchive', 'Mailarchive: ', ['class' => 'col-sm-3 control-label']) !!}
        <div class="col-sm-6">
            {!! Form::select('mailarchive', ['-' => 'No', 'Gold' => 'Gold', 'Silver' => 'Silver', 'Bronze' => 'Bronze'], null, ['class' => 'form-control', 'v-model' => 'mailarchive']) !!}
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group" v-show="mailarchive !== '-'">
        {!! Form::label('instance', 'Instance: ', ['class' => 'col-sm-3 control-label']) !!}
        <div class="col-sm-6">
            {!! Form::select('mailarchive', ['Select' => 'Select', '1' => 'SV01', '2' => 'SV02'], null, ['class' => 'form-control']) !!}
        </div>
    </div>
    {!! Form::submit() !!}
{!! Form::close() !!}
</div>
<script>
new Vue({
    el: '#example'
});
</script>
```

Here is a working example on jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/zj8hwjc9/1/

Comment: Wow, thank you very much! That was a very god explanation! It works!

Answer (score 0):

You will need to bind the first field to a var with v-model="mailArchive" then on the second form group use v-show="mailArchive !='-'"

Comment: Can you give me an example?